# How to loop an IList of objects and set state to modified for SQL

Tags: sql, asp.net, asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to loop a list of objects and set them as modified before posting to SQL. but I am getting an error Object Reference not set to an instance of an object.

setting a single instance of object works fine using

```
    [BindProperty]
          public Models.Ord Order { get; set; }
Order = await _context.Ord.SingleOrDefaultAsync(m => m.Id == id);
        _context.Attach(Order).State = EntityState.Modified;
```

But this return an error.

```
[BindProperty]
        public IList<OrdLn> OrderLineList { get; private set; }

        OrderLineList = await _context.OrdLn.Where(o => o.OrdId == id).ToListAsync();

        foreach (OrdLn p in OrderLineList)
        {
            _context.Attach(p).State = EntityState.Modified;
        }
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The 'Q' in LINQ stands for "Query". LINQ is not meant to update objects.

You can use LINQ to find the object you want to update and then update it "traditionally".

When you are using SingleOrDefault function, the object in remote or database until you make changing the entity type(changing to new class), so there you can make change on the entity and db operation able to carryout.

When you are using List function. the object is in memory of the application so there is relation between db and will not able to carryout db operate operation.

All of these return types have interfaces inherit from IEnumerable, which you should make sure you understand. That interface basically lets you use the class in a foreach statement (in C#).

- **IList** : is everything that ICollection is, but it also supports adding and removing items, retrieving items by index, etc. It's the most commonly-used interface for "lists of objects", which is vague I know.
- **IQueryable** : is an enumerable interface that supports LINQ. You can always create an IQueryable from an IList and use LINQ to Objects, but you also find IQueryable used for deferred execution of SQL statements in LINQ to SQL and LINQ to Entities.

Comment: I think you have missed some words in your text. 
do you have a code solution?

Comment: the first thing is don't use list, second thing is value in the object is null